# How to prevent ServiceStack from leaking private server information during 403 Forbidden Response

Tags: servicestack

Servicestack Version: 3.9.71.0
Target Framework: .NET 3.5
Program background: has been in production use for over 3.5 years

Recently due to a customer security audit items were brought to our attention. All but one have been eliminated as IIS configuration changes.

The last item identified describes a situation in which the probing software accessed an endpoint without the proper authentication. This was fine and the expected result was the 403 Forbidden. The unexpected result was that the response body is displaying certain internal information of the server.

Based on quite a few articles I have searched it seams the the response body information being returned is a result of how Servicestack my be configured.

I realize this is a fairly older version of Service Stack. My preference would be to identify an IIS setting to override a forbidden response. Aside from that an option to just return a status code of 403 without the additional information. The third would be to create and use a custom 403 response object to control what is revealed.

Any guidance or help would surely be appreciated.. Thank you in advance.

[image: Customer Probe Results][image: My Postman results]

Answer (score 0):

[ServiceStack v3](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3) is a very old version of ServiceStack last updated in 2013. If you need to make any changes you'll need to create a [custom build from its Sources](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3#source-code-for-v3)

Looking at the v3 sources for how it [resolves the ForbiddenHttpHandler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory.cs#L112-L113):

```
ForbiddenHttpHandler = config.GetCustomErrorHttpHandler(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
```

It looks like you'll be able to override what HttpHandler is used by [overriding the CustomHttpHandlers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/EndpointHostConfig.cs#L624), e.g:

```
EndpointHostConfig.Instance.CustomHttpHandlers[HttpStatusCode.Forbidden] = MyHandler {...}
```

Comment: Allow me to ask another question in order to understand your response a little more thoroughly. When you refer to a "Custom Build From its Sources" are you referring to the entire source base of what makes up ServiceStackV3 and not just my user source code based on that version of ServiceStack? Is there not a way to override a custom handler from my user code? Even more curious to me, understanding that security concerns have changed over the years, was this a common case that when receiving a 403 it responded with a private server path such as this? Thanks...

Comment: I’m referring to a custom build of ServiceStack v3 from the src’s I linked to, My answer includes a potential way to override in user code based on v3 behavior, ServiceStack now only returns debug info is when in DebugMode.

Comment: Okay, I am continuing as you describe. Will update further moving forward. Thanks.

Comment: So besides the original finding of private server info being disclosed of any 403 Forbidden. If you attempt to hit the metadata page but incorrectly spell it your response is "Handler for Request not found:" with a whole page of information being disclosed some of which is private which is seen as a security risk some not. Is there no way in V3 to catch or filter response objects based on type to at least remove the raw body portion and just return the status code? The just seems like overkill to prevent portions of a response body from being shown.

Comment: The statement of concern displayed above... App.DebugLastHandlerArgs:... is it possible that this is displaying because the app was built in debug mode instead of release?

Comment: @JakRuzL Not likely, if you really believe the info is a security risk you’ll need a custom build that strips out the info you don’t want

Comment: just a couple more questions and I'll leave you alone. First is a concern of the sources for V3 you linked to. I am seeing a readme.md update moving to 3.9.60. All of the .dll versions in our current project is 3.9.71.0. Am I able to access that branch of source?  Since the fix seems to affect just ServiceStack.dll, I was trying to eliminate recompiling the rest of the dependencies. We are using ServiceStack.dll, ServiceStack.Common.dll, Servicestack.Interfaces, ServiceStack.OrmLite, ServiceStack.OrmLite.SQlServer, ServiceStack.Redis, ServiceStack.ServiceInterface, ServiceStack.Text

Comment: @JakRuzL It would be binary compatible but NuGet doesn't support you just updating just one of the .dll's so you'd most likely need to switch to using local .dll's instead of NuGet. Did your Security Audit team mention what's the worst thing that could happen by knowing the directory name in IIS's public C:\inetpub\ folder? i.e. What's the actual security risk?

Comment: this is the verbiage that is in the report they have provided us and our customer.

**Synopsis:** The remote web application discloses path information.
**Description:** At least one web application hosted on the remote web server discloses the physical path to its directories when a malformed request is
sent to it.
Leaking this kind of information may help an attacker fine-tune attacks against the application and its backend.
**Solution:** Filter error messages containing path information

Comment: @JakRuzL Right, would definitely like to know the worst possible harm knowing a directory name in IIS’s c:\inetpub could possibly do? I’d press for an real world example if they can’t give you one, IMO it’s just wasting customers resources into supporting an unnecessary custom build.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217749/discussion-between-jakruzl-and-mythz).

Comment: moved my last question into the chat, if you have time to look it over. thanks